# How to use same Environment variable for all spring modules

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables

I have 3 spring modules with their own Configuration files.
e.g. SP1,SP2, SP3.
SP3 module initialize context for all 3 modules using

```
private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  validatorContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SP3.class, SP2.class, SP1.class);
```

SP3 have property file which gets loaded for SP3 only. i would like to use SP3 environment variables in other modules as well.
So if properties are loaded once its properties shall be used by other modules.

My other module i.e. SP2 configuration file has following code :

```
@Autowired
    @Bean
    public ValidationConfigurationLoader validationConfigurationLoader(final Environment environment){
        ValidationConfigurationLoader validationConfigurationLoader = new ValidationConfigurationLoader();
        validationConfigurationLoader.setValidationConfigurationFilePath(environment.getProperty("referenceccda.configFile"));
        validationConfigurationLoader.setUnmarshaller(castorMarshaller());
        return validationConfigurationLoader;
    }
```

Note: it is not setting variables for SP1 & SP2 modules but SP3 as it has the property file.
But when i set Env. variables from eclipse then it works

[image]

Comment: If the properties for S3 really are shared and there's custom code related to them then perhaps they could be put in a separate module that just loads the properties and all three of the others could depend on it?

Comment: Actually, Env variables are being used in SP2 & SP1 and i set those in property file under SP3 module and initializing context in SP3. now those Variable must be autowired in SP2 & SP1

Comment: If properties are being set in the spring context then I'd expect them to be available in the application that your modules feature in (and available for all the modules). But properties not environment variables. Could you give an example of a property that you expect to be set and which you can't use?

Comment: Presumably `referenceccda.configFile` is an example. But how is that getting into the spring context (an application.properties file or something more custom)? You say you want to 'Autowire' the properties - does it work if you use @Value to get access to that property?

Comment: In eclipse (as shown above) i have set -->referenceccda.configFile variable and all are available to each module. but through property file they are not.

Comment: Presumably the project you are using is https://github.com/siteadmin/reference-ccda-validator ? I am wondering what happens if you try to access with @Value like https://github.com/siteadmin/reference-ccda-validator/blob/1968c633793e528516c30c31ca71433de9eea3e0/src/main/java/org/sitenv/referenceccda/validators/vocabulary/VocabularyCCDAValidator.java#L23 ?

Comment: correct, if i lonely use the project and have property files configured it works fine. NO issue. 
I now made a JAR of that RefCCDAValidator and used in another project . i.e. SP3. now its not picking from properties